# Can I show "App" Would like send you notifications alert after event in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications

I am creating an app with push notifications and facebook login. For push notifications, the alert comes when you open the app, "App" Would like send you notifications. I want to display it after facebook login.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can register for push notifications from anywhere in project. In your case you have to register for push notifications after you successfully login user with Facebook. Give a call to *registerToReceivePushNotification* after login completes and handle delegates in AppDelegate.

`Objective C:`

```
#pragma mark - push notificaiton
-(void)registerToReceivePushNotification 
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
}
```

`Swift:`

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotifications()
```